# Flatten array and lookup corresponding value and write to new array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Currently I iterate through a set of linkedObjects to to search for an isMatch. This test looks to see if element.id is present in the array obj.resource_ids if it is then we add the printable-string from the matching appointmentObj to an array in printStr.

The problem comes because value.resource_uniqueids could be an array containing many ids but my test only ever finds one.

Somehow I need to match all the ids in value.resource_uniqueids. - It might be the case that I need to add a new appointmentObj for each value.resource_uniqueids and then concatenate each equivalent printable-string

I hope this makes sense. How do I add a new ${currentMatch.printable-string} for each match of value.resource_uniqueids

Thanks !

```
_.forEach(appointmentObj, (value,i) => {

    // value.resource_uniqueids is always an array, most of the time it only has one element
    // but sometimes it can have more than one which means we only match one below in isMatch function

    _.set(appointmentObj[i], 'resource_ids', value.resource_uniqueids ); 
    _.set(appointmentObj[i], 'printable-string', `${value.title}, ${moment(value.created_at).format( 'Do MMMM YYYY')}` );
});    

linkedObjects.forEach((element, index) => {

    let isMatch = appointmentObj.find((obj) => {
        return _.includes(obj.resource_ids,element.id);
    });

    if(isMatch) {
        linkedObjects[index]['content']['printstring'] = `${currentMatch.printable-string}`;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a note, you can write `linkedObjects[index]['content']['printstring'] = ...` more cleanly as `element.content.printstring = ...`. And then you can remove `, index` from the `.forEach()` callback parameter list since you aren't using `index` any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem comes because value.resource_uniqueids could be an array
>   containing many ids but my test only ever finds one.

`Array.prototype.find()` returns a single matched element from within an array. Use `Array.prototype.filter()` if expected result is more than one matched result from within the iterated array.

Comment: Thanks I will try this.